# understanding excessive DNS traffic to cron.sh

Tags: dns, cron

I noticed that my domain cron.sh is receiving more than a million DNS requests a month, exceeding its dyn.com quota.  Set up djbdns for it and observe that thousands of hosts around the world want its IP via A query, but it is not followed by an http request nor by an email to *@cron.sh.  How can I find out what they are trying to do?  Could it be a known cron misconfiguration, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the DNS server has recursive on and they are using your DNS server for this reason. I would make sure you disallow recursive DNS.

Comment: The zone used to be at dyn.com, not sure whether the setting there was allowing recursive.  But why cron.sh and not any other?